# Nutch - clone website

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

I am playing with Apache Nutch and I am crawling a website successfully. I want to make a clone of a website with Nutch so that I can access the crawled webpages offline. Is there a way to do that? I'm looking for something like an endpoint that receives a url and returns the content of the webpage as if I were GETting the url with curl.

I know there are more specialized solutions like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), but I want to know if it is possible to use Nutch to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need this now but anyway I am putting my answer. Of course it's possible using Apache Nutch.After injecting seed urls and generating segments of urls to fetch, when you execute the fetch command -

```
$ bin/nutch fetch -all
```

The Hbase(it's very conventional to use Hbase as storage for Nutch) `webpage` table structure will be like this -

```
webpage : {
  key : "com.exampe.dev:http/",
  f : {
    bas : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "http://dev.example.com/" 
    },
    cnt : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD X...rest of page content" 
    },
    fi : {
      timestamp : 1293676557658,
      value : "\x00'\x8D\x00" 
    },
    prot : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "x02\x00\x00" 
    },
    st : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "x00\x00\x00\x02" 
    },
    ts : {
      timestamp : 1293676557658,
      value : "\x00\x00\x01-5!\x9D\xE5" 
    }
    typ : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "application/xhtml+xml" 
    }
  },
  h : {
    Cache-Control : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "private" 
    },
    Content-Type : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
    },
    Date : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "Thu, 30 Dec 2010 18:13:21 GMT" 
    },
    ETag : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : 40bdf8b9-8c0a-477e-9ee4-b19995601dde" 
    },
    Expires : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "Thu, 30 Dec 2010 18:13:21 GMT" 
    },
    Last-Modified : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "Thu, 30 Dec 2010 15:01:20 GMT" 
    },
    Server : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "GSE" 
    },
    Set-Cookie : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "blogger_TID=130c0c57a66d0704;HttpOnly" 
    },
    X-Content-Type-Options : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "nosniff" 
    },
    X-XSS-Protection : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "1; mode=block" 
    }
  },
  mk : {
    _injmrk_ : {
      timestamp : 1293676557658, 
      value : "y" 
    },
    _gnmrk_ : {
      timestamp=1293732629430, 
      value : "1293732622-2092819984" 
    },
    _ftcmrk_ : {
      timestamp : 1293732801833, 
      value : "1293732622-2092819984" 
    }
  },
  mtdt : {
    _csh_ : {
      timestamp : 1293676557658, 
      value : "x80\x00\x00" 
    }
  },
  s : {
    s : {
      timestamp : 1293676557658, 
      value : "x80\x00\x00" 
    }
  }
}
```

The column named `cnt` under `f` column family will contain the whole html content of your page. So you can use this to clone the page obviously.

Moreover, you can write custom plugins implementing `Parser` or `ParseFilter` interfaces to catch the whole content of page. The code will be very straight-forward.